# WIX create directory upon multiple files installation

Tags: directory, wix, bundle

I'm working on installation package of an application with a few additional ones, required for it to work. Here's a structure I have so far:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Bundle ...>
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef ... />

    <Chain>
        <MsiPackage ... />
        <ExePackage ... />
        <MsiPackage ... />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

I need to create a few directories for one of the applications (these directories won't be used upon installation). But I have no idea how to accomplish this.

I've found a lot of examples of creating directories under `<Product>` section. But when I use `<Directory>` tag inside `<Bundle>`, it says, that: "The Bundle element contains an unexpected child element 'Directory'".

I'm new to this tool and might be missing some basic concept. Can anyone help me understand where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundles install packages and packages are what update the machine. So to create directories, do so in the application package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bob. Could you provide more details on this? Should I make some custom package in WIx or what? I would be greatly appreciated for any examples :)

Comment: Or maybe there's another, better, approach for implementing my task?

Comment: Add `Directory` and `CreateFolder` elements to your application's MSI package.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've tried that and got the "The MsiPackage element contains an unexpected child element 'Directory'." error. I'm not sure if there any other way to accomplish this task .. but I did like this: <MsiPackage SourceFile="Blah.msi"><Directory Id="SomeDir" Name="SomeDir"></MsiPackage>. What's wrong with me? :)

Comment: You need to add those elements *in* the actual .msi package, not in your bundle authoring.

Comment: Aaah .. I see now. Thank you for the help!